# Ubuntu 16.04 - No Sound

Tags: sound, 16.04

I have just downloaded Ubuntu for the first time. However, I can't get any sound and I cannot figure out how to sort it. Please help!

Comment: See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: This hasn't worked I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential issue which isn't listed in the troubleshooting guide Jos [linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770445/ubuntu-16-04-no-sound#comment1151058_770445). Even if your sound isn't muted in the desktop volume controls, it could still be muted or turned down very low in `alsamixer`.

This [guide](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/) has basic instructions for using `alsamixer`. For me, the crucial one was to look for the `MM` symbols that mean certain outputs are muted.